Semaphore causing deadlock on WPF
DoAsync, ConnectFtpAsync, ConnectDbAsync all works on Console project when the number of tasks exceeds the semaphore's limit.
However ConnectFtpAsync and ConnectDbAsync except DoAsync cause WPF project to freeze when the number of tasks exceeds the semaphore's limit.
ButtonPressedAsync() which is the outermost call doesn't use the ConfigureAwait(false) and ConfigureAwait(false) used at inner call shouldn't matter.
Removing the ConfigureAwait(false) from inner calls didn't solve the problem.
Removing semaphore or not exceeding the limit of semaphore solved the problem.
FluentFTP and Oracle is used for the given code.
3 examples are tested separately.

Why do ConnectFtpAsync and ConnectDbAsync freeze WPF project?
Why DoAsync doesn't freeze WPF project?


    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await ButtonPressedAsync();
    }
    
    private static async Task ButtonPressedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var connectionLimit = 4;
            var smph = new Semaphore(connectionLimit, connectionLimit);
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
    
            for (var i = 0; i < connectionLimit + 1; ++i)
                tasks.Add(DoAsync(smph));
    
            //for (var i = 0; i < connectionLimit + 1; ++i)
            //    tasks.Add(ConnectFtpAsync(smph));
    
            //for (var i = 0; i < connectionLimit + 1; ++i)
            //    tasks.Add(ConnectDbAsync(smph));
    
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    
    private static async Task DoAsync(Semaphore smph)
    {
        smph.WaitOne();
    
        await Task.Delay(500).ConfigureAwait(false);
    
        smph.Release();
    }
    
    private static async Task ConnectFtpAsync(Semaphore smph)
    {
        smph.WaitOne();
    
        var ftpConnection = new AsyncFtpClient(
            host: "ip",
            port: 21,
            user: "id",
            pass: "pswd");
    
        await ftpConnection.Connect().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
        smph.Release();
    }
    
    private static async Task ConnectDbAsync(Semaphore smph)
    {
        smph.WaitOne();
    
        var credential = "credential";
        using var dbConnection = new OracleConnection(credential);
        await dbConnection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await dbConnection.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
        smph.Release();
    }



Semaphore and other kernel events are not really compatible with async because they completely block execution.
So what you are getting is a classic Async Deadlock, because the code is being run on the UI thread and locking up waiting for the semaphore. This happens primarily in GUI apps such as WPF, rather than console apps where there is normally no synchronization context.
This can be avoided using ConfigureAwait(false), but you need to ensure that that is used all the way down the stack, which in the case of external libraries is hard to ensure.
The real answer is to never block on async code. You need a wait event that can suspend execution via async, such as SempahoreSlim.
Note also that Release should be called in a finally to ensure it always gets called even in the event of an exception.
private static async Task ButtonPressedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var connectionLimit = 4;
        using var smph = new SemaphoreSlim(connectionLimit, connectionLimit);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (var i = 0; i < connectionLimit + 1; ++i)
            tasks.Add(DoAsync(smph));

        //for (var i = 0; i < connectionLimit + 1; ++i)
        //    tasks.Add(ConnectFtpAsync(smph));

        //for (var i = 0; i < connectionLimit + 1; ++i)
        //    tasks.Add(ConnectDbAsync(smph));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ;
    }
}

private static async Task DoAsync(SemaphoreSlim smph)
{
    await smph.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(500).ConfigureAwait(false);
        // do other stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        smph.Release();
    }
}

private static async Task ConnectFtpAsync(Semaphore smph)
{
    await smph.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try
    {
        // make sure to dispose your connection
        using var ftpConnection = new AsyncFtpClient(
            host: "ip",
            port: 21,
            user: "id",
            pass: "pswd");

        await ftpConnection.Connect().ConfigureAwait(false);
        // do stuff with FTP connection
    }
    finally
    {
        smph.Release();
    }
}

private static async Task ConnectDbAsync(Semaphore smph)
{
    await smph.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try
    {
        var credential = "credential";
        await using var dbConnection = new OracleConnection(credential);
        await dbConnection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        smph.Release();
    }
}


I would add .ConfigureAwait(false); to the await smph.WaitAsync(); as well. There is nothing after that that requires the original context.

True although we don't know what the real code is doing.

Yea, the real code might include interactions with UI components, although it's not very likely. The same can be said for the real code inside the catch (Exception ex) block, in which case the .ConfigureAwait(false) should be removed from the await Task.WhenAll(tasks);.

In the first part of the question, OP says they tried in a console app and encountered different behavior. May be worthwhile to also explain why that is and why that experiment didn't help finding the problem?

Yeah added a bit on that as well. Feel free to improve my answers if you have something to add.

Am I understanding correctly? 1. After reaching the limit, the UI thread is locked by a semaphore. 2. An inner part of the external library, which doesn't use .ConfigureAwait(false) and was called from the previous task before hitting the limit, tries to return to the original context(UI), which is locked. @Charlieface

That's certainly what it appears to be although other deadlocks are possible as well.

@Charlieface Thank you for clarifying. I really appreciate it.
